# Routes are not working in cPanel deployed json-server

Tags: node.js, cpanel, json-server

I recently tried to deploy json-server to my interserver's shared hosting plan via cPanel.
I uploaded the app and configured a Node.js app and I'm able to access the endpoint via 'https://soltonbaev.com/json-server/api/contacts' however the jsonServer.rewriter() is not rewriting the "/api/" route to the "/".

In addition I cannot access the individual object via it's id, like for instance "https://soltonbaev.com/json-server/api/contacts/1". Server returns 404.

So clearly, JSON server is not picking up the routes when it is supposed to.

Here is the content of my server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const cors = require('cors');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('database.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.use(
   jsonServer.rewriter({
      '/api/*': '/$1',
   })
);

server.use(cors({origin: process.env.REMOTE_CLIENT_APP, credentials: true}));
server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(
      ` JSON Server is running on ${process.env.REMOTE_CLIENT_APP}:${port}}`
   );
});
```